# Illegal instruction (core dumped)

Tags: rust

How can I debug this with rust-0.10? It works for smaller numbers like 13195... 
I think I'm hitting some limit with uint

```
use std::vec;
use std::num;
use std::iter;

fn int_sqrt(n: uint) -> uint {
    num::sqrt(n as f64) as uint
}

fn simple_sieve(limit: uint) -> ~[uint] {
    if limit < 2 {
        return ~[];
    }

    let mut primes = vec::from_elem(limit + 1, true);

    for prime in iter::range_inclusive(2, int_sqrt(limit) + 1) {
        if primes[prime] {
            for multiple in iter::range_step(prime * prime, limit + 1, prime) {
                primes[multiple] = false
            }
        }
    }
    iter::range_inclusive(2, limit).filter(|&n| primes[n]).collect()
}
fn main() {
    let limit: uint = 600851475143;
    let limithalf: uint = limit/2 as uint;
    let primes = simple_sieve(limithalf);
    let sieved: ~[uint] = primes.move_iter().filter(|&n| limit % n == 0).collect();
    println!("{:?}", sieved);
    let mut max = 0;
    let f = |x: uint| if x > max { max = x };
    for x in sieved.iter() {
        f(*x);
    }
    println!("{}", max);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the huge allocation(s) you're trying to do: the `vec::from_elem` call in `simple_sieve` is trying to allocate `600851475143/2` bytes, i.e. approximately 280 GB. The allocation is failing (i.e. `malloc` returns NULL) which ATM just causes Rust to abort.

This simpler program indicates the problem:

```
extern crate libc;

fn main() {
    let n = 600851475143 / 2;
    let p = unsafe {libc::malloc(n as libc::size_t)};
    println!("alloc {}", p)
}
```

prints `alloc 0x0` for me. Try using smaller numbers. :)

Comment: What a day. Another answer after 10 minutes. Thanks